# Visual studio project files changes and Mercurial

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial

I am a developer used to work with VSS and TFS source Control where only one developer is allowed to Checkout any file including visual studio files.
I am planning to use Mercurial in private project , I found Mercurial does not support file lock as VSS or TFS, I thought about SVN, but I need to have clones of the source control repository both online and on local harddisk, so Mercurial may be the best for me.

my problem is that without locking Visual studio Project File, then when i add a file to the project, say I added a class, and on the same time one of my team members adds another class, we both will be able to commit the two added classes, but only one version of the project(either mine or his) will be the last committed one, and one of our classes will be ignored.

how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

> how can I prevent this?

With Mercurial, you'll commit your changes (locally).  When you grab the changes of your team member, you'd *merge* the two sets of changes together.  This typically works very cleanly, and can be done without worry (it's rare that it fails in the merge or even needs special help).  The project files then get both sets of changes, at which time you can commit these changes locally, then push them into your shared repository.

This allows everyone on your team to work without worry about what other people are doing, though the responsibility to merge the changes together falls on the shoulders of whomever wants to push their changes up last - but this tends to work very smoothly, as Mercurial does a good job of merging the changes together (normally).